# How to set up JSONstring for jqGrid/turn object into Json for jqGrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am trying to dynamicalyl populate my jqGrid...

I have been running into a hell of a time getting my jquery grid to populate with data.  How would you set up your jquery string?  I create an object like so...

```
public static object JsonHelper(TemplateModel model){

            var values = model.Template;
            var JsonDataList = new {
                total = 1,
                page = 1,
                records = model.Template.Count,
                rows = (from val in values
                        select new {
                            cell = //new string(
                                ":[\"id\" :\"" + val.EncounterId +",\""+
                                "\""+val.MRN + ",\""+                                    
                                "\""+val.HostpitalFinNumber +",\""+                                  
                                "\""+val.FirstName+",\"" +                                    
                                "\""+val.LastName +",\"" +                                    
                                "\""+val.DateOfBirth.ToString() +",\""+                                    
                                "\""+val.CompletedPathway +",\""+                                    
                                "\""+val.CompletedPathwayReason +",\""+                                    
                                "\""+val.PCPAppointmentDateTime.ToString() + ",\""+                                    
                                "\""+ val.SpecialistAppointmentDateTime.ToString() + ",\""+                                    
                                "\""+val.AdminDate.ToString()+"\"]"                            
                        }).ToString()//.ToArray()
            };
            return JsonDataList;
        }
```

That is just an object,
However I return the object using the `Json` methbod call...

Here is what I do...

```
return Json(DataRepository.JsonHelper(model.FirstOrDefault()), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I get the model from the search call...  I have know idea what I am doing wrong... Can somebody give me a simple example of how to turn a simple object into json?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into [Google's gson library.](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) I used it when working with JSON and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I don't want to add yet another layer of complexity where something could break down.  I just need to figure out why what I am doing does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just used a string builder and a good JSON debugger to get the right strings, and it appears as though it works...